# Managing Java threads in a CPU instruction pipeline simulator

Tags: java, multithreading, cpu, cpu-architecture

I have implemented a 5-Stage CPU instruction pipeline simulator in Java using multi-threading.

Each Stage is a thread that performs mainly below 3 functions, also there is a queue (of capacity 1) in-between every two stages.

1. Receive from the previous stage.
2. Process i.e. perform its main responsibility.
3. Forward to the next stage.

> ```
>     @Override
>     public void run() {
>         while (!(latchQueue.isEmpty())) {
>             fetch();
>             process();
>             forward();
>         }
>     }
> ```

Simulation works fine. This is where I’m stuck, I want to be able to simulate only a specified number of clock cycles. so, the simulator should stop/pause once it has reached the specified number of cycles.

As of now, I have started all the 5 threads and let it simulate the processing of all the instructions rather than limiting it by clock cycles.

How can I accomplish this? do I need to pause thread when specified clock cycles have reached? If so how can I gracefully handle suspending/stopping the threads? Please help me in choosing the best possible approach.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Is the `latchQueue` the queue between this stage and the next one? YOu should show more code to understand. If the `latchQueue` transiently becomes empty, won't the thread incorrectly terminate? I.e., if the second stage processes everything send to it, won't the `while` condition become false resulting in the end of the run method?

Comment: I would simply change to loop condition to "true" and use an explicit "stop" object to terminate the queue (while !empty seems wrong to me). Then you can simply let the queue starve to pause it.

Answer (score 1):

You are already using some concurrent queue to communicate between the threads (exactly how it works isn't clear because your code example is quite incomplete).

So you can count cycles at the first stage, and use that same mechanism to communicate: shove a sentinel object, which represents "time to stop/pause this thread", onto the queue for the first stage, and when processed it pauses the processor (and still forwards it to the next stage, so all stages will progressively shut down). For example, you could extend the type of objects passed in your queue so that the hierarchy contains both real payload objects (e.g., decoded instructions, etc) or "command objects" like this stop/pause sentinel.

Another asynchronous solution would be to `Thread.interrupt` each thread and add an interrupt check in your processing loop - that's mostly to gracefully shut down, and not so much to support a "pause" functionality.

Comment: The word you're looking for is ["sentinel"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value), not "poison" (i.e. value that will trap, often used for detecting reads of unitialized values or [similar cases](http://blog.hostilefork.com/poison-memory-without-asan/), to take a random example from google)

Comment: No, I was looking for poison.

Comment: But sentinel fits perfectly for what you're doing: detecting a termination condition.  As I understand it, reading a poison value is an error, by definition.

Comment: @PeterCordes yes, sentinel would also be a great word! It's versatile and could be applied here for sure (although it has a fairly broad meaning and in linked structures it has already a [specific meaning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_node) inconsistent what I'm talking about doing here). More to the point, it wasn't the word I was _looking for_!. I use "poison object" to refer specifically to the case where an object is inserted into a queue to kill a thread. Perhaps it's not a standard use, but honestly that's a pretty narrow case anyway, so that's how new uses start, right?

Comment: Notice how the "Sentinel Value" wikipedia article I linked starts with the note "Not to be confused with sentinel node".  Feeding a poison value to something should make it abort or segfault or otherwise trap and exit *abnormally*.  This is not what we want.  Diluting the meaning of "poison value" when there is a very specific term for exactly what you mean ("sentinel value") is not good.

Comment: @PeterCordes I think you are tilting at windmills here. I already agreed that sentinel is a _fine_ word to use here. I disagree, however, that _poison value_ is something that should make it "abort or segfault or otherwise trap and exit abnormally". Perhaps that's a way you've heard that word used in some specific low-level problem domain, but concepts like "segfault" hardly even applies to a discussion in safe higher level language or in an abstract discussion about queues.

Comment: _In fact_, when discussing queuing systems, the word "poison" _is_ often used for a value, perhaps malformed or otherwise unusual, that stops a queue consumer in its tracks. So it's a very short leap to understand that here I'm talking about an intentional poison that by-design stops the processor. Note again, I'm not saying sentinel is _wrong_. It's fine. Perhaps it's better even since the set of people who understand "sentinel" in a general programming sense is probably much larger than the set of people who understand "poison" in a queuing sense (as your complaints about its use indicates).

Comment: ... so since I could care less which is used (other than to rebut your suggestion that I was _looking for_ a word other than the one I deliberately used), I'll change it to sentinel.

Comment: I'm willing to believe that "poison" does have a broader definition than the uses I've come across.  I didn't know about the use in queueing systems;  I wish you'd said that earlier.  Sorry to get on your case like that, but until just now I believed that you were way out in left field on this one.  (And thanks for changing the wording.  I suspect that it will sound more correct to more people this way.  You missed one occurrence, though, in the last paragraph.)

Comment: *concepts like "segfault" hardly even applies to a discussion in safe higher level language or in an abstract discussion about queues.*  Exactly.  That's why I thought it was a terrible choice of word!  But actually I think I was wrong with that definition.  Filling uninitialize memory (or uninitialized list/array values) with 0xDEADBEEF would be an example of poisoning.  If you see that in a variable, you know you made a mistake and read something you shouldn't have.  But the idea is that it's poison: your algorithm dies if it eats any.  That's *my* (possibly wrong) understanding of the term.

Comment: In the end I liked sentinel better since I reread the requirement and noted that it said the OP wanted to "stop/**pause**" the simulation. I hadn't noted **pause** before, and was only thinking of gracefully stopping the threads and shutting down the simulation. In the case of _pause_ though, poison seems wrong. If you want to be a terminology-lawyer perhaps sentinel is also wrong since it's not going to be the last value any more (assuming pause is followed by restart). Sometimes I call this type of queue node a "command node" in contrast to a "payload node".

Comment: @PeterCordes what I meant is that context is important. If I was in a hospital and talked about _poisoned nodes_, no one is going to think about programming, they are going to wonder about my lymph nodes - in the same way as sentinel would be interpreted differently if you were speaking in a military context. So I kind of reject just googling a word and saying "here's the most common/best meaning" - you have to at least consider the meaning within the context, which here is `java`. So the odds that I am mistakenly talking about memory poisoning are pretty much zero.

Answer (score 0):

Will following work?

Share following class `CyclesCounter` between all your threads representing stages. It has `tryReserve` method, getting `true` from it means thread has got enough "clock cycles" for its' next run. Getting `false` means there's not enough cycles left. Class is thread-safe.

After getting `false`, perhaps, your thread should just stop then (i.e., by returning from `run()`) -- no way it can get enough nr of cycles (due to your requirements, as I understood them), until whole session is run again.

```
class CyclesManager {

    private final AtomicInteger cycles;

    CyclesManager(int initialTotalCycles) {
        if (initialTotalCycles < 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Negative initial cycles: " + initialTotalCycles);

        cycles = new AtomicInteger(initialTotalCycles);
    }

    /**
     * Tries to reserve given nr of cycles from available total nr of cycles. Total nr is decreased accordingly.
     * Method is thread-safe: total nr of is consistent if called from several threads concurrently.
     *
     * @param cyclesToReserve how many cycles we want
     * @return {@code true} if cycles are ours, {@code false} if not -- there's not enough left
     */
    boolean tryReserve(int cyclesToReserve) {
        int currentCycles = cycles.get();
        if (currentCycles < cyclesToReserve)
            return false;
        return cycles.compareAndSet(currentCycles, currentCycles - cyclesToReserve);
    }

}
```